# Error executing maven goal for Apache Camel with spring archetype

Tags: spring, maven, apache-camel

I'm new to maven and I'm trying to create a Apache Camel project using maven. I ran the following maven command to run a maven goal (all in the same command line): 
`mvn archetype:generate 
-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app –DartifactId=camel-first-app 
–DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.camel.archetypes –DarchetypeArtifactId=camel-archetype-spring -DinteractiveMode=false -X`

I get a build failure from maven with an exception saying:

"org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory"

I'm doing this without having the POM.xml file in the current directory because in the Maven Guide it says you don't need one to begin with.

Comment: Just type `mvn archetype:generate` and then use it in interactive mode its much easier. In the big list you can find the camel archetypes and type the number to select it and so on

Comment: Solved. Yeah, it was simpler that way, thank you for the reply @Claus.